# Are there any good web accessibility training courses/tutorials (online)?

Tags: accessibility, web, wcag

I'm looking for recommendations for online courses on web accessibility. I know the actual guidelines are out there, but my aim is to find a survey of guidelines and best practices in an easy-to-parse online course or tutorial format, to avoid too much in-depth reading (time resources are constrained). I'm looking for "the" course or tutorial designers/developers would recommend to other designers/developers. Anything in between "too general/high level" and "read the manual" would be great, if it exists!

I have some training in accessibility and design, but would like to better formalize the knowledge with an aim toward implementation practices.

I found a few courses on Udemy, Udacity, Lynda, etc. but am not sure any of these are up-to-date or detailed enough. The standouts are listed below, though, if anyone who's encountered them can comment on their quality.

- Web Accessibility by Google (Udacity) -
  https://www.udacity.com/course/web-accessibility--ud891
- Web Accessibility: Learn Best Practices, Tools & Techniques (Udemy) -
  https://www.udemy.com/website-accessibility-course/

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if you've checked Google's introductory tutorial from their official website. You can check it out **[here](https://webaccessibility.withgoogle.com/course)**

The course is to-the-point with all the neccessary technical "must-know" lessions and a hands-on project at the end of the course.

I had taken this course and have found it to be very precise.

Hope this helps!